# Canonical question for Java "resources in JAR"

Tags: discussion, canonical

Based on the community's positive response to [my canonical question about Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null), I think it would be helpful to have a similar canonical about using classpath resources from [JAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) files or similar packaged applications. (The question "I used `File` and it didn't work in a JAR file" shows up on my feed about once a day.)

I'm posting this to solicit feedback, particularly on whether there's a good existing canonical that I managed to overlook.

Comment: How about [Loading resources like images while running project distributed as JAR archive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9864267)? While accepted answer itself may not be very detailed it contains links to more detailed questions and specific IDE solutions.

Comment: @Pshemo Hmm. Possible, though could be a bit more focused.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken there are two scenarios. One where the resource is suppose to be inside the jar and the other where the resource is not.

Comment: I think the real canonical would be this question: [Different ways of loading a file as an InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676250/different-ways-of-loading-a-file-as-an-inputstream/676273#676273)

Comment: @Scratte If the resource is not supposed to be inside the jar, this problem doesn't arise (at least not in this form).

Comment: @Lino That's a different problem, which addresses the proper path to use _when already using the correct `getResourceAsStream`_.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I understand, but it seems to me to be a source of confusion. I see questions for clarification in comments, like "where are the files located?"

Comment: I've found some potential canonicals, which could be edited / extended, e.g. [Reading a resource file from within jar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20389255) or [How do I read a resource file from a Java jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/403256) or [Java Jar file: use resource errors: URI is not hierarchical](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10144210) and potentially also this: [How to get a path to a resource in a Java JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/941754)

Comment: @Lino That 10144210 looks promising.

Comment: The more I look at existing answers (including the dozen or so I’ve written), the more I’m convinced that a brand new canonical question and answer are needed.  The answers are all addressing specific mistakes, even when they try to describe the general case.

Comment: Is there a list somewhere of questions that have canonical answers?

Comment: @jaco0646 Not that I'm aware of. Maybe worth a new meta post?

Comment: I made an attempt at a canonical answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63890530/why-does-this-code-displaying-an-image-give-an-error-when-build-into-jar).

Answer (score 14):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar) with its accepted answer, as identified by @Lino, seems to clearly isolate the problem usage and explain why it doesn't work and what to do instead. I propose using this as a canonical dupe and performing a mass Mjollnir.

Comment: There is no canonical answer though. The accepted answer uses getClass().getResourceAsStream() which is quite an error prone way to load resources. There is also a distinct lack of using try-with-resources in all the answers.

Comment: @Gimby What is your recommendation in place of `getClass().getResourceAsStream(String)`?

Comment: You should use `ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream(String)`. Otherwise, it could fail when you have a subclass in a different package. Unless, you *want* to potentially end up at different, sub-class specific resources, of course. Usually, you don’t.

Comment: @Holger Fair enough; I have so infrequently loaded relative-path resources I overlooked that.

Comment: Even for absolute paths there’s the hypothetical case of a subclass in a different module that can’t access the resource.

Comment: @Holger `getResourceAsStream()` is `@CallerSensitive` - the permissions of the caller are used, not of the subclass.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn when you do `getClass().getResourceAsStream(String)`, the resource will be searched in the subclass’ module. The caller on the other hand, is not the subclass.

Comment: So it's looking like subtle pitfalls in the existing solutions plus the introduction of Jigsaw mean that a new version is needed.

Comment: Well, the superclass can't access the resource in the subclass's module.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- definitely a new version is needed. Key factors are Class.getResourceAsStream() Vs ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream() and the problems that modules add to the mix. I would write one myself, but I haven't researched into the module specifics yet.

Comment: @Gimby Is it necessary to delve into those subtleties? Would it be sufficient for purpose to say "Use `Foo.class.getResourceAsStream()`"?

Comment: IMO it's not needed to explain the different ways to call getResourceAsStream, but it *is* needed to make sure the asker understands why File doesn't work. They should have that facepalm moment where they realize the thing they're trying to load isn't a file.

Comment: To me, if an answer doesn't mention the difference between `ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream(relativeToClass)` and `ClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(relativeToClasspath)`, it's not a "canonical answer".